# How should I organize my ajax actions files

Tags: php, jquery, code-organization, project-organization

I would like to know what's the best way to organize my php project with ajaxActions files.

At the moment I have a few `./process/ajaxAction_pagename.php` files containing my actions like this:

```
if ($action=="actionName")
{
//code
}
```

I'm just wondering if there is a better (or more standard) way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using an minimal mvc framework to handle your actions? 
Checkout: [Cupcake](http://github.com/fernyb/Cupcake) php framework it needs documentation but it's really minimal.